# Responsive doesn't work in phone

Tags: css, media-queries

I create a website and I make hem responsive with @media, All things are right, when I slimming with Mozilla I don't have any problem

but when I see my site with my phone all things are lost, I see a disaster :'(

I make Mozilla size {
   1280px, 980px, 800px, 768px, 360px, 320px
}

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
body {
 background:url(img/Saad.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
 background: transparent url("img/logo.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
 width: 212px;
 height: 89px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 85px;
 margin-left: 702px;
}

.gauche {
 margin-top : -253px;
 float: left;
 width: 250px;
 height: 75px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 15px; 
 }

.rs li {
 float: left;
 width: 47px;
 height: 47px;
 margin:0px 4px 0px 0px;
}

.players {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 321px auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 90px;
}

.hicham{
 display: block;
 margin: -563px 140px 79px 130px;
 position: absolute;
}
.hand{
 display: block;
 margin: -495px 0px 94px 357px;
}

.basket{
 margin: -906px 0px 98px 260px;
}

.foot, .hicham, .hand, .basket{
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.foot:hover, .hicham:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
          transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

.hand:hover, .basket:hover{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
          transform: rotate(10deg);
}

a li{
list-style: none;
}

.fb {
 background: transparent url("icon/facebook.png") no-repeat center top;
}

.twitter {
 background: transparent url("icon/twitter.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
 }

.instagram {
 background: transparent url("icon/icon4.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
}

.youtube {
 background: transparent url("icon/youtube.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
}

.sponsors {
 display: block;
 width: auto;
 height: 65px;
 background: #FFF url("img/pubb.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
 margin-top: 320px;
}

.copyright {
 font-family: monospace;
 color: #FFF;
 text-transform: inherit;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
}
}


/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 800px) {
body {
 background:url(img/Saad.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
 background: transparent url("img/logo.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
 width: 212px;
 height: 89px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 85px;
 margin-left: 555px;
}

.gauche {
 margin-top : -253px;
 float: left;
 width: 250px;
 height: 75px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 15px; 
 }

.rs li {
 float: left;
 width: 47px;
 height: 47px;
 margin:0px 4px 0px 0px;
}

.players{
 width: 700px;
 margin: 354px auto;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 height: 90px;
}

.hicham{
 display: block;
 margin: -563px 140px 79px 130px;
 position: absolute;
}
.hand{
 display: block;
 margin: -495px 0px 94px 357px;
}

.basket{
 margin: -906px 0px 98px 260px;
}

.foot, .hicham, .hand, .basket{
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.foot:hover, .hicham:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
          transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

.hand:hover, .basket:hover{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
          transform: rotate(10deg);
}

a li{
list-style: none;
}

.fb {
 background: transparent url("icon/facebook.png") no-repeat center top;
}

.twitter {
 background: transparent url("icon/twitter.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
 }

.instagram {
 background: transparent url("icon/icon4.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
}

.youtube {
 background: transparent url("icon/youtube.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
}

.sponsors {
 display: block;
 width: auto;
 height: 65px;
 background: #FFF url("img/pubb.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
 margin-top: 320px;
}

.copyright {
 font-family: monospace;
 color: #FFF;
 text-transform: inherit;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
}
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
 body {
 background:url(img/Saad.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
 background: transparent url("img/logo.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
 width: 212px;
 height: 89px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 85px;
 margin-left: 526px;
}

.gauche {
 margin-top : -237px;
 float: left;
 width: 250px;
 height: 75px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 15px; 
 }

.rs li {
 float: left;
 width: 47px;
 height: 47px;
 margin:0px 4px 0px 0px;
}

.players{
 width: 700px;
 margin: 353px auto;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 height: 90px;
}

.hicham{
 display: block;
 margin: -563px 140px 79px 130px;
 position: absolute;
}
.hand{
 display: block;
 margin: -495px 0px 94px 357px;
}

.basket{
 margin: -906px 0px 98px 260px;
}

.foot, .hicham, .hand, .basket{
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.foot:hover, .hicham:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
          transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

.hand:hover, .basket:hover{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
          transform: rotate(10deg);
}

a li{
list-style: none;
}

.fb {
 background: transparent url("icon/facebook.png") no-repeat center top;
}

.twitter {
 background: transparent url("icon/twitter.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
 }

.instagram {
 background: transparent url("icon/icon4.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
}

.youtube {
 background: transparent url("icon/youtube.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
}

.sponsors {
 display: block;
 width: auto;
 height: 65px;
 background: #FFF url("img/pubb.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
 margin-top: 320px;
}

.copyright {
 font-family: monospace;
 color: #FFF;
 text-transform: inherit;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
}
}


/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 360px) {
 body {
 background:url(img/Saad.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
 background: transparent url("img/logo.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
 width: 212px;
 height: 89px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 22px;
 margin-left: 70px;
}

.gauche {
 visibility: hidden; 
 }



.players{
 margin: 100px 0px 0px -374px;
}

.foot{
 margin: -1px 0px 0px 417px;
}

.hicham{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.hand{
 display: block;
 visibility: hidden;
}

.basket{
 visibility: hidden;
}



.sponsors {
 display: block;
 width: auto;
 height: 65px;
 background: #FFF url("img/pubb1.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
 margin-top: 320px;
}

.copyright {
 font-family: monospace;
 color: #FFF;
 text-transform: inherit;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
}
}


/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

body{
background:url(img/Saad.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

.players {
    margin: 131px 0px 0px -405px;
}

.logo {
 margin: -9px 0px 0px 49px;
}


.gauche {
 visibility: hidden; 
 }


.sponsors {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 25px;
    background: #FFF url("img/pubb1.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
    margin-top: 148px;
}

 

.foot{
 margin: -28px 0px 0px 461px;
 width: 200px;
}

.hicham{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.hand{
 display: block;
 visibility: hidden;
}

.basket{
 visibility: hidden;
}

.copyright {
 font-family: monospace;
color: #FFF;
text-transform: inherit;
display: block;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 6px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12px;
}
}
```

Any help ?

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you posted your css media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile browsers try to make your site look good, so they don't render your site pixel for pixel, like you might expect. For example: let's say your phone has a width of `250px`, but your phone might tell your website that it is `500px` or even `1000px` wide, which in turn make your @media queries obsolete.

After that long explanation, this is what you need to add to the `<head>` of your html code: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`, that should make your phone (and all other phones) tell your website what the phone's width REALLY is.  And all your @media queries should work.

Hope that helped!

---

Here's some articles worth checking out for more information:

1. CSS Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/
2. MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
3. Envato Tuts+: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972

Comment: First it's work just for phone Or all things like tablets .. etc ? 
I make the meta code, that's work but I have some problems for example I make somethings display none where the size is phone, but when I see with my phone I see this things ? How I can fix it ?

Comment: @sayou It will work with all devices.  The `display: none;` issue might be that your phone is to big to trigger the media queries. Try making your media queries larger, i.e. if you think your phone is 320px, try making the HTML element disappear at 500px, just to test if your media query really works.  If your HTML element disappears, then you know your media query is working and it's targeting a smaller screen size than your phone has.  If the HTML element still doesn't disappear, then you know that your media query isn't working or that it doesn't select the element you really want.